# using javascript variables in javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am just getting used to regular expressions and am unsure of how to use JavaScript variables in them.

My code is:

```
if (window.location.hostname == 'localhost') {
    var $sURLDomain = 'http://localhost/';
}
else {
    var $sURLDomain = 'http://mysite.com';
}


$('#content a[href^=$sURLDomain]').addClass('internal');
```

Essentially I am setting the variable `$sURLDomain` based on whether I'm on my local or live url.

I then want to test whether my links starting with the `$sURLDomain` variable and use jQuery to add a class to those specific links only.

This doesn't seem to be functioning, so am unsure of how to achieve this.

Comment: Please clean your keyboard: the `.` seems to be stuck.

Comment: oi!Its a quirk i have when typin......etc..etc

Comment: Note that the attribute selector `[attr^=…]` does not use regular expressions for comparison. It uses simple string comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#content a[href^="'+$sURLDomain+'"]').addClass('internal');
```

Or:

```
$('#content a').filter(function() {
    return this.href && this.href.substr(0, $sURLDomain.length) != $sURLDomain;
}).addClass('internal');
```

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: It depends on the value of `$sURLDomain` if the `filter` method is required. But what do you mean by rendering? The JavaScript engine does not render anything within this code.

Comment: The first one has worked great for me..thanks...Wondering how you would identify links which dont start with the sURLDomain variable..thanks

Comment: @namtax: Use the `:not()` selector: `'#content a:not([href^="'+$sURLDomain+'"])'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#content a[href^=$sURLDomain]').addClass('internal');
```

1. JavaScript doesn't do PHP-style string interpolation. You have to say `'#content a[href^='+sURLDomain+']'`.
2. It's unusual to begin your JavaScript variables with a `$`. Some people use it as a kind of ‘Hungarian notation’-style flag that the variable is a wrapper object from jQuery or other library. It's arguable whether that's a good idea, but either way don't prefix your variables with `$` just because that's what PHP does.
3. The `[^=...]` selector checks the start of the attribute value for a literal string. Contrary to the question title, **there is no regex here**. The only connection to regular expressions is the use of `^` to mean ‘the start of the string’.
4. If there's a character that's special for selectors in the URL, such as a `]` or `\`, the lack of escaping means the selector expression will break. Probably unlikely in this particular case, but it may well be simpler (and easier to deploy given changing domain names) to say:

   ```
   for (var i= document.links; i-->0;)
       if (document.links[i].hostname===location.hostname)
           $(document.links[i]).addClass('internal');
   ```

Comment: Ha! `.hostname` FTW (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533785(VS.85,loband).aspx) You're loving these obscure properties on `<a>` elements aren't ya.

Comment: Obscure?! That's a basic JavaScript feature going back to Netscape 2, yer whippersnapper! ;-)